# How To Resume OS X El Capitan download after shutting down MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mac-appstore

I went to download the OS X El Capitan on my MacBook Air. Yesterday I've downloaded 2GB with 256kbps download speed. After downloading it all day, time to let the MacBook Air rest. This morning I went to open my MacBook Air, to the Apps Store, clicked the Free Upgrade. That time I was thinking: "Why is it not the resume button? Uh oh, something's not right." Typed in my password, download started, but from 0% Help? D:

Comment: "After downloading it all day, time to let the MacBook Air rest. "  What was the indicator that your MBA needed to "rest?"  Let the file download.  If it's not fast enough, you can spend a few bucks and get the DVD shipped to your home.

Comment: @Allan, Who's going to ship it? Apple? **No**, because OS X El Capitan **is not** available on DVD from Apple! OS X 10.7 had a USB installer you could buy from Apple as well as downloading from the App Store. However, for the ordinary everyday consumer, since OS X 10.8 it has only been available as a download from the App Store.

Comment: You're right...I confused Microsoft's option to purchase a DVD or USB installer of Win10 with what Apple offers.  Seems that's not a bad option considering the OP's situation.  He could take it **into** an Apple store and have it installed like Apple's webpage says....

Comment: The way I said "After downloading it all day, time to let the MacBook Air rest." is to shut down it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resume the download after a shutdown. But your MacBook Air doesn't need to "rest". So start the download again and don't shut down the MacBook until it's finished, even if it takes days.

Comment: Will the download able to resume after I sleep the MacBook Air? Like closing the lid?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Just keep it running until your download is finished.

Answer (score 0):

That's horrible! Yeah, you usually can't resume after a shutdown.

If the reason you needed to shutdown was because your computer was getting hot, what you can do is take two pencils and put them underneath your computer so it has better air flow. But you actually don't need to worry about this because computers have build it over-heat protection and can shutdown on their own if they get too hot.

On a side note, you don't really need to shutdown often on a Mac. I normally only shutdown once or twice a week, but usually only because I need to use Windows in Boot Camp.